# The distinction between ctl and cntl?

Tags: c

I searched that

> In computing, ioctl is an abbreviation of input/output control

while

> fcntl - file control

what's the difference between `ctl` and `cntl`?

Comment: The letter 'n'.  Seriously, there's no deep meaning here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger And then there's `iscntrl` and `clnt_control` and `unctrl`.

Comment: Just different flavours of stupidity. `control` is just 6 letters and because of it, there's no obvious need to create obscure abbreviations.